# Trying to load dataset but getting this error

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

This is code where i trying to load dataset
can you tell me effective way to read from drive

path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/images/images'

```
angry = load_images(path + '/train/angry/')
print('Loaded angry dataset: ', angry.shape)

disgust = load_images(path + '/train/disgust/')
print('Loaded disgust dataset: ', disgust.shape)

fear = load_images(path + '/train/fear/')
print('Loaded dataA: ', fear.shape)

happy = load_images(path + '/train/happy/')
print('Loaded dataA: ', happy.shape)

neutral = load_images(path + '/train/neutral/')
print('Loaded dataA: ', neutral.shape)

sad = load_images(path + '/train/sad/')
print('Loaded dataA: ', sad.shape)

surprise = load_images(path + '/train/surprise/')
print('Loaded dataA: ', surprise.shape)

dataA = vstack((angry, disgust),(fear,happy),(neutral,sad),(surprise))
```

this is the error i am getting

Error:

````
<ipython-input-3-61a5def9c2d9> in <module>
     16 
     17 # load dataset train
---> 18 angry = load_images(path + '/train/angry')
     19 print('Loaded angry dataset: ', angry.shape)
     20 

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in list_directory_v2(path)
    766   """
    767   if not is_directory(path):
--> 768     raise errors.NotFoundError(
    769         node_def=None,
    770         op=None,

NotFoundError: Could not find directory /content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/images/images/train/angry671.jpg```



I want to read the dataset from google drive
````

Answer (score 0):

To effectively read a dataset from Google Drive in Colab, you can follow these steps:

Mount your Google Drive by running the following code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Once your Google Drive is mounted, you can access your files by specifying the path to your files. In your case, you can replace the path variable in your code with the following:

```
    path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/images'
```

To load the images, you can use the ImageDataGenerator class from the tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image module. Here's an example of how you can use it:

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=path+'/train',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True
)

enter code heredataA = train_generator.next()[0]
```

This will create a train_generator that will read the images from the train directory, apply the specified preprocessing (rescale=1./255), resize the images to (224,224) and convert them to RGB color mode. The batch_size parameter specifies the number of images to load at once, and the class_mode parameter specifies that the labels should be categorical (one-hot encoded). Finally, the next() method is called on train_generator to load the next batch of images, and only the data is saved in the dataA variable.

You can repeat this process for each of your image categories to load the entire dataset.